# React.useCallback: do I need to pass functions in array of dependencies along with dependencies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

React docs example shows only `[a, b]` as dependencies. Function `doSomething` is not passed.

```
const memoizedCallback = useCallback(
  () => {
    doSomething(a, b);
  },
  [a, b],
);
```

But later docs reads:

> every value referenced inside the callback should also appear in the dependencies array.

My question: do I need to pass `doSomething` as well?

```
const memoizedCallback = useCallback(
  () => {
    doSomething(a, b);
  },
  [a, b, doSomething],
);
```

Comment: How is `doSomething` defined? Can it ever change?

Comment: if `doSomething` is defined _within_ the component or custom hook, or is passed as a parameter, then yes. If it's defined outside the function scope, then no.

Answer (score 4):

Technically it's not required if it doesn't change, but it can bring unexpected behavior, so just for simplicity you need to pass all things you used inside if it's declared in component or comes from props. Also if you are using eslint, there is awesome [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) for hooks which is de-facto standard